# PWM Comparator types for Class D

Tags: amplifier, comparator, multisim, class-d

I've started simulating a Class D amp, but it seems the [MAX999](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX961-MAX999.pdf) (I saw recommended elsewhere on this site) isn't working. Could anyone point me in the direction of why? I swapped in an LM311 which jumped around (due to being too slow I believe) and a virtual ideal comparator (placed in parallel here to save on screen shots) which works fine.

I'd like to understand why the 999 isn't working, so if anyone can point me in the direction as to why, and even make some recommendations, I'd much appreciate it. I've looked at the data sheet and nothing is jumping out at me.

It's not shown on the screenshot, but the tri is 200kHz, the supply current to the 999 is 6.5mA and the current on pin 3 is 16uA RMS, if it's relevant.

[image: PWM simulation]

Comment: Have you tried a much more simple test for the 999 alone? A simple ramp and a fixed voltage, for example. Try breaking down into pieces.

Comment: I had, but on a new design page. Your question prompted me to run it on this design page and it's stuck on high again, which is interesting. Thanks for the idea, I'll look in to it and report back :)

Comment: I copied the whole thing on to a fresh design file and it works fine. Was something within Multisim then. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Where is your output filter and feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this wasn't a design/electronics issue, but something within Multisim.

I'd been working on several different designs on the same design sheet and had convergence problems previously, running the Convergence Fixer a few times, so it had probably changed some settings that are beyond me. I won't say it was a Multisim fault as for all I know the program was working as intended.

Lesson learnt: If breaking the problem in to pieces (as a concerned citizen advised) make sure to keep as many constants as possible, in this case, running the simplified comparator circuit on the same design sheet so as to use the same parameters.